# Texture disappear on joining

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I am making a tree, in which I have a texture for the central tree object or bark, and branches have a different texture.

I applied the branches on tree with particle system.  Till then the textures were fine.

Then I convert the particle system and delete the particle system.

Then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> join to the main bark texture with the branches, with the bark or central stem as parent.

Doing this, texture from my branch material disappears.

Please anyone help me out.  ASAP.! Thanks

Comment: Check if you have UV maps named differently on each object

Comment: @Denis yes..  I have named uv maps differently on each.  Still doesn't work

Comment: the UV names should be exactly the same before you link the objects

Comment: @Denis man you saved my life..  I was busting my ass on this thing for last 2 days.  God bless you buddy..  

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that both UV Maps have the **same name**, otherwise the textures will not share the same space when they are assigned to a single object.

Comment: I switched over to RizomUV and my workflow collapsed. This SINGLE sentence saved me so much misery I can even begin to explain.