# Why meshes lose material when joined?

Tags: texturing, materials

When separate, meshes keep their materials. When I join them, some of them seem to lose material. Correct material still displays in the material properties panel. Assigning it again doesn't change anything, neither does finding image texture again. What can be wrong? How to join meshes without losing texture? (The object starts to look black)[image]

Comment: check this answer, it might  be what your looking https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93726/texture-disappear-on-joining

Comment: **I found solution** in this video :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaIxZT_gLw0
the problem was diferently named UVs

Comment: Thanks! :)  this helps, there is sililar video i found, and posted below. Thank you!!!